# 301 redirect works on other pages, but not on home page

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I have used 301 redirects on my website, which redirects pages with .html to pages without .html extension.
For e.g.  www.codersvolt.com/services.html redirects to 
www.codersvolt.com/services

Those redirects works, but when I open home-page, 
www.codervolt.com , it redirects to www.codersvolt.com/index/
which does not work. It should open home page.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.codersvolt.com$1/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited my code and It works fine now.

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ /$1/
```